# Where we should place RabbitMq?

Tags: rabbitmq

Suppose that if we are creating the project on `PHP` and going to use `RabbitMq` for Queuing.
Then which one will be the better solution?

1. Putting `Apache` and `RabbitMq` on the same server?
2. Putting `Apache` and `RabbitMq` on different servers?

Comment: That'll depend on the scale of the project.

Comment: @JohnEllmore, the project goal is to handle a lot of traffic and requests.

Comment: Larger projects will want to separate applications like web servers and message systems onto different servers. If you don't, it'll be more difficult to scale down the road.

Answer (score 0):

**Surely second option to put the apache and rabbitMq on different server is better.**

Because you will get 2 different server(processors). If one is overloaded then it will not affect the other. And all queue related load will be on different server.